# Mudar contéudo numa dada posicao num array multidimensional dentro de uma estrutura

Tags: c, array-multidimensional

Estou a ter problemas em modificar o conteúdo numa dada posicao de um array multidimensional que está dentro de uma estrutura. Tenho duas estruturas `struct TabelaFilial` e `struct ArrTabela`. A estrutura `struct TabelaFilial` está a ser apontada por um tipo incompleto `typedef struct TabelaFilial *TabelaFiliais`e a estrutura `struct ArrTabela` por `typedef struct ArrTabela *ArrTabelaFiliais` . A estrutura `TabelaFilial` tem uma matriz com 14 linhas : `char *(*m)[14]` e a estrutura `ArrTabela` tem um array com 3 posicoes em que cada posicao aponta para a estrutura `TabelaFilial`. Aqui estão as estruturas :

```
struct TabelaFilial

{
 char *(*m)[14];
};

typedef struct TabelaFilial *TabelaFiliais;

struct ArrTabela
{
 TabelaFiliais tab[3];

};

typedef struct ArrTabela *ArrTabelaFiliais;
```

Inicializei assim as estruturas:

```
void iniciaTabela (TabelaFiliais t)
{
    t = (TabelaFiliais ) malloc (sizeof (struct TabelaFilial));
    t->m = malloc (sizeof (char*) * 9); 

    int l , c;

    for (l = 0 ; l < 14 ; ++l)        
     for (c = 0 ; c < 9 ; ++c)      
        t->m[l][c] = NULL;

}

void iniciaArr (ArrTabelaFiliais arr)
{
    int i;
    arr = (ArrTabelaFiliais)malloc(sizeof (struct ArrTabela));

    for (i = 0 ; i < 3 ; ++i)
      iniciaTabela(arr->tab[i]);


}
```

Pretendia agr aceder ao array `tab[3]` na posicao 0 da estrutura `ArrTabela`
e mudar o seu conteúdo.
Usei esta pequena função:

```
void TabelaFilial (ArrTabelaFiliais arr)
{
    int l , c;


    for (l = 0 ; l < 14 ; ++l)        
     for (c = 0 ; c < 9 ; ++c)      
       strcpy ((arr->tab[0]->m[l][c]) , "||||||");
}
```

No entanto , obtive um `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`.
***O que estou a fazer mal? E como posso corrigir?***

Comment: o campo da `tabelaFinal` está `char *(*m)[14]`, quando a variável está entre parenteses, quer dizer que ela vai armazenar métodos, tente fazer sem usar o parenteses, `char *m[14]`. E verifica se está alocando a memória dos elementos corretamente.